# Visual Studio 2008 performance profile plugin or tool

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, performance, profiling

I need a plugin for Visual Studio 2008 or some external tool to measure duration of my C# methods. I know about built in profiler, but it measures the whole usage percent that method takes from the application start to the end.

I have a method which is a root. I need to know how long other methods called from the root are executing including all methods in the call stack of this root. Each time the root is called a new result set should be presented.

If I am wrong about VS profiler, please correct me.

**UPDATE** Freeware is more likely.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Answer (score 1):

[DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) profiler does the trick